# Mac OSX HTML5&CSS3 Text Editor

Tags: macos, html, css, text-editor

I am searching an [HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) & [CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/) text editor for Mac OS X. What would you suggest?

Please give a short description as well as some information about pricing (free? commercial? trial?).

By the way, I am aware that there is the ability to take [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/)/[Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) to make certain Windows applications work in OS X. If you definitely know that a certain Windows HTML5 & CSS3 editor works in Mac OS X and it is worth it, please mention it.

Thank you!

Comment: Could I be given a chance of modifying my question by pointing out what is subjective and argumentative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/), [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), and [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) are--in my opinion--the most popular text editors for web development. TextMate has a 30-day free trial and is $57 USD. Coda is $99 USD and does not have a free trial (to my knowledge). And BBEdit is $99 USD and has a free trial (don't know how long it is).

For a free text editor, you can use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) from the same people who made BBEdit.

My personal preference is Vim / MacVim; but learning the Vim language is probably overkill if you're just doing just HTML / CSS. I would recommend trying out all of these and seeing what you like the most.

EDIT: A final note, everything I listed here is highly extensible and if there is a feature you like in one, it has most likely been ported to one or more of the other editors as well. Keep this in mind, because you shouldn't immediately dismiss any particular editor for what it offers as a default install.

If you're really particular about your editor (which you should be, as it's the single most important tool in your arsenal) then you should also look at available plugins for each code editor to get a true picture of what they can and cannot do.

Comment: @Sven: I just downloaded it. :)

Comment: @Sven glad to hear it. I've been meaning to try it out for instances when I just don't feel like vimming, but I didn't want to shell out the $99 for it.

Comment: I'm going to suggest Coda, it's very powerful and useful across multiple languages. It's my personal favorite :]

Answer (score 2):

I realise it might be overkill, but I really like using NetBeans for Javascript / HTML5 stuff.  The JS completion is really helpful and it handles things like Canvas 2D API methods.

One drawback is that it doesn't seem to support CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend Textmate, if you willing to spend money. Its very comfortable to code html/css/js.

Personally I code in [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). They're crossplatform compatible and opensource.

edit: both provide tons of plugins :)

Comment: Do these editors support HTML5?

Comment: @Alerty Yes they do. But so you know, Eclipse is an IDE and not an editor. For HTML/CSS it wouldn't be your best option, but for actual programming it is very powerful.

Comment: Well yes eclipse is a complete IDE. I thought its worth mentioning escpecially if many people work on a project.

Answer (score 1):

I like Aptana Studio. If you take the time to configure it's preferences it's a powerful editor.

Comment: is working it in HTML5?

Comment: This post was a long time ago. Now I use Komodo edir